# Liquid: How to combine two "UNLESS" conditions?

Tags: jquery, shopify, liquid

I am working in Shopify liquid, and I'm looking for a clear and easy way to run a code (in this case initialize jquery) only if two conditions are NOT true.

1. The template is NOT the cart
2. The template is NOT a product template with more than one product variant.

In these cases I already initialized JQuery before with more simple IF- conditions. So now I want to avoid initializing JQuery again for these cases.

Can I use this:

```
{% unless template contains 'cart' or template contains 'product' and product.variants.size > 1 %}
  {{ 'jquery-2.2.3.min.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
{% endunless %}
```

Is it clear that "and" is referring to the 'product'-template? So like `If X != true OR (Y != true AND Z = true)`?

Otherwise, do I need to use the following in order to make sure JQuery is not initialized twice?

```
{% unless template contains 'cart' %}
    {% unless template contains 'product' and product.variants.size > 1 %}
        {{ 'jquery-2.2.3.min.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
    {% endunless %}
{% endunless %}
{% unless template contains 'product' and product.variants.size > 1 %}
    {% unless template contains 'cart' %}
        {{ 'jquery-2.2.3.min.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
    {% endunless %}
{% endunless %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your solution**

First off the second alternative you proposed with the nested code will work in either the two forms:

1. With **cart** check **outside** and product inside
2. With **product** check **outside** and cart inside

**General mechanism**

Shopify Liquid evaluates operators like `and` and `or` in `{% if %}` and `{% unless %}` statements from right to left so for example if you have:

```html
<div>

  {% unless false or false and true %}
    {{"The evaluated condition is false"}}
  {% else %}
    {{"The evaluated condition is true"}}
  {% endunless %}

</div>
```

This will output `{{"The evaluated condition is false"}}` because:

1. false and true evaluates to false
2. false or false evaluates to false
3. `{% unless false %}` outputs `{{"The evaluated condition is false"}}`

I consider a single `{% unless %}` statement neater and would avoid the nesting but you can go with either solution.

Comment: Because you can't use parentheses in Liquid if/unless comparisons, to avoid confusion I usually recommend using `assign` to store some subset of the variables to compare (either the ANDs or the ORs, depending on what makes sense in the situation) then run my if/unless using only AND or OR, never both. For this question, I might use `{% if template contains 'product' and product.variants.size > 1 %}{% assign product_has_variants = true %}{% endif %}{% unless unless template contains 'cart' or product_has_variants %}<stuff>{% endunless%}`